# How to create links to download resources on another domain a href another-sub-domain

Tags: javascript, html

a href on a another sub domain doesn't download.

a solution can be javascript or any html5 combination

down;load resource

```
<a href="https://sub.domain.com/a/b" download> down;load resource </a>
```

doesn't download

Comment: ```download``` can only download image

Comment: @Mayuri That's not right. It can download other file types too.

Comment: yes but not a site

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a CORS issue (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). There is a library that acts as a CORS alternative, Check this link https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain